# Syntax in documentations, parameters

Tags: javascript, documentation

I've seen a lot of documentation give code example as

```
axios.get( url [, config] );
```

I just need clarification as to why there would be a comma inside the square brackets.

If the second parameter just a config object, shouldn't it be:

```
axios.get( url, {config} );
```

Comment: The comma inside the brackets means the comma is part of the optional portion. `(url)` is valid, but `(url,)` is not. And if `config` is an object `{config}` is wrong. That would be an object containing config.

Comment: Thank you for this.